# Why do absolute elements stack up on each other instead of stacking one after the other?

Tags: html, css, css-position

How can get both `#row1` and `#row2` in the following code to be visible, one after the other vertically, as if there wasn't any `absolute/relative` positioning involved (though without removing the positioning properties)? I.e. having the two `.row` `<div>` to appear as "normal" block elements.

```css
body { position:relative; min-height: 2em; width: 100%; }
.container {position:absolute;}
.row {position:relative;}
.col1, .col2 {position: absolute;}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="row1" class="row">
      <div class="col1">Hello</div>
      <div class="col2">World</div>
    </div>
    <div id="row2" class="row">
      <div class="col1">Salut</div>
      <div class="col2">le monde</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

(Sample also available as a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wjrNQ/).)

I need the elements to have the positioning provided in the CSS rules, for reasons excluded here.

The content is programmatically dynamic; I don't know the elements' heights beforehand, so a solution can't be based on specifying an absolute length (e.g. 'px') anywhere.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wjrNQ/1/

Comment: Well - do not use absolute positioning! As long as col1/col2 have absolute positions, they will ignore any changes on rows.

Comment: Don't use positioning at all http://jsfiddle.net/wjrNQ/2/ though am not answering as am not sure what you are asking here

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Well you have some weird wishes here so let me explain you what those positions really mean in CSS and how they work, using `position: relative;` is just like using `static` `position`, the difference is making an element `position: relative;`, you will be able to use `top`, `right`, `bottom` and `left` properties, though the element will move, but physically it will be in the document flow..

[image]

Coming to `position: absolute;`, when you make any element `position: absolute;`, it gets out of the document flow, hence, it has nothing to do with any other element, so in your example
you have `.col1, .col2 {position: absolute;}` which are positioned `absolute` and since both are out of the document flow, they will overlap... Because they are already nested under `position: absolute;` parent i.e `.container` and since no `width` is assigned, it will take the minimal `width` and hence, your elements overlap, if you cannot change your CSS(which according to me doesn't make any sense why you can't change) still if you want, than you can do is this..

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/wjrNQ/3/) (Without removing any of your `position` property) And this is really dirty

---

For the `s` characters, it will be at the `top` as your container element is out of the flow, and hence, no `height` will be considered in the document flow, unless and until you wrap that `s` in some element, and bring it down with, `margin` `padding` or CSS Positioning.

---

## CSS Positions Explained

As I commented, here are few examples of how CSS Positioning actually works, to start with, there are 4 values for `position` property i.e `static` which is the default one, `relative`, `absolute` and `fixed`, so starting with `static`, nothing to learn much here, elements just stackup one below the other unless they are floated or made `display: inline-block`. With `static` positioning, `top`, `right`, `bottom` and `left` won't work.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mD6n6/)

---

Coming to `position: relative;` I've already explained you in general, it's nothing but same as `static`, it stacks up on other element, it is in the document flow, but you can tweak the elements `position` using `top`, `right`, `bottom` and `left`, physically, the element stays in the flow, only `position` of the element is changed.

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/mD6n6/1/)

---

Now comes `absolute` which generally many fails to understand, when making an element `absolute` it gets out of the document flow, and hence it stays independent, it has nothing to do with other elements positioning unless it's overlapped by other `position: absolute` element which can be fixed using `z-index` to change the stack level. The main thing to remember here is to have a `position: relative;` container so that your `absolute` positioned element is *relative* to that `relative` positioned element, else your element will fly out in the wild.

It's worth noting that `position: absolute;` element when positioned `absolute;` inside an `absolute` positioned parent element, than it is relative to that element and *not relative* to the grand parent element which may be positioned `relative`

[**Demo 3**](http://jsfiddle.net/mD6n6/2/) (Without `position: relative;` container)

[**Demo 4**](http://jsfiddle.net/mD6n6/4/) (With `position: relative;` container)

---

Last is `position fixed`, this is same as `absolute` but it flows along when you scroll, it's out of the document flow, but it scrolls, also, `position: fixed;` element cannot be `relative` to any container element having any type of `position`, not even `relative`, `position` `fixed` element is always `relative` to the viewport, so designers use `position: absolute;` when they want to have a `fixed` `position` behavior but `relative` to parent and tweak the `top` property `onScroll`.

[**Demo 5**](http://jsfiddle.net/mD6n6/5/)

Comment: By using `position: absolute;` and leaving out `top` and `left`, you can also take the element out of the flow and have it displayed inside the parent: http://jsfiddle.net/mD6n6/113/

Answer (score 2):

What you want, is not possible without modifying the CSS `position` property. However, what you can do without touching the existing CSS, is overriding it with a more specific selector

```css
.row .col1, .row .col2 {
    position: relative;
}
```

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wnpr2/1/)

Answer (score 1):

when `position:relative` is used, the **page layout will occur normally** before being offset by `top, left` values, however [position:absolute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) will [ignore the document flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18598031/using-positionabsolute-while-keeping-it-inside-the-document-flow). The `relative` ones will work with no changes but absolute must be changed

```
.col1, .col2 {display:inline-block;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/C4bQN/

EDIT: Depending on your circumstances, maybe you can wrap your table in an absolute positioned div then use normal document flow within the table?

```
<div class="absolute-wrap">
    <div class="row"> 
        <div class="col"> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```