# Z-index on relative positioning

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am newbie to HTML. I searched whether `z-index` works on relative positioned elements or not, and I found yes it works.

But the problem is when i am trying its not getting stacked.

```
<style>
.div0{position:relative;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;height:auto;z-index:1;}
.div1{position:relative;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;height:auto;z-index:1;}
.div2{position:relative;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;height:auto;z-index:2;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="div0">
    <div class="div1">Text One</div>
    <div class="div2">Text Two</div>
</div>
</body>
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZZGz7/1/)**

Comment: What do you mean by stacked?

Comment: @Mr.Alien In z-index order, text two overlapping text one

Comment: `position:relative;top:0px;left:0px;` will not show any difference in position of divs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all lets refactor your CSS, you won't need `width:100%;` and `height: auto;` as `width` of the `block` level element is always `auto` but it takes entire horizontal space unless if it's floated or it's turned to `inline-block` or `inline` and as far as `height` is concerned, it's `auto` by default so you don't need to define it.

Secondly, if you are trying to stack the `div` on on another than consider using `position: absolute;` for the child elements instead of `position: relative;`, if you want to stick with `position: relative;` than you will need to define the `top` value in negative.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZZGz7/2/)

```
.div2{
    position:relative;
    left:0px;
    z-index:2; 
    top: -15px;
}
```

---

But make sure that `position: relative;` does change the position of the element, but it reserves the space physically in the flow, whereas, `position: absolute;` won't.

---

Also, if you want to apply some same properties to your child elements, you can use selectors like

```
.div0, .div1, .div2 {
   /* Common properties here */
}

.div2 {
   /* Override common properties, or you can define unique ones as well. */
}
```

Comment: For more information on how CSS positioning works, you can refer my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20718577/how-css-positions-work-why-absolute-elements-stack-up-on-each-other-instead-of)

Answer (score 1):

Update the position of .div1 and .div2 to `absolute`.

```
.div1{position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;height:auto;z-index:1;}
.div2{position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;height:auto;z-index:2;}
```

Comment: By absolute it can be done, but what about relative?

Comment: @Ishank Gupta  Ritesh Kumar asking with relative position.. you said answer with absolute position

Comment: absolute positioning is best for such implementation, you need to shift the element to overlap the other div if you want to implement it using relative positioning.

Answer (score 0):

relative positioned elements top & left properties works from current x-y position of element. In this case, you can use negative top to stack div2 over div1.