# Positioning scheme is influenced to child elements

Tags: html, css, css-position

Consider the following HTML markup:

```
<div><span></span></div>
```

and a stylesheet:

```
div {
    border: 5px solid yellow;
    position: absolute;    
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 40px auto;
}

span {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    background: aqua;
}
```

It's OK. Content is displayed as I'm expected: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z8BSs/2/).

But if I'm trying to delete `position:absolute` from the `div`, then something incomprehensible is occuring. [jsFiddle after deleting absolute position of div](http://jsfiddle.net/z8BSs/3/).

Q: Why `span` get out from the border of parent div and div's positioning scheme is influenced to `span` rendering?

Comment: You should apply position: relative to parent element if you want to wrap the positioned absolute span

Comment: @laaposto It's typo, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `position: absolute;` under a `position: absolute;` element, than the child element is relative to that `absolute` parent element.

So, since the parent is now `static`, and `position: absolute;` elements are **not relative** to *static* positions.

Inorder to have an `absolute` element relative to parent, use `position: relative;`

```
div {
    border: 5px solid yellow;    
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 40px auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

For more information on CSS Positioning, read my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20718577/how-css-positions-work-why-absolute-elements-stack-up-on-each-other-instead-of).

Answer (score 0):

Just change the `div` `position` to `relative`.

http://jsfiddle.net/z8BSs/5/

Comment: My question is about another thing. I want to understand why the span element is taking all available screen place?