# CSS Understanding margin in absolute positioned elements

Tags: html, css, position, margin, absolute

I am having some problems with margins in absolutely positioned elements.

As already answered in another question, margins in absolutely positioned elements are dictated by the first not statically positioned parent container.

[CSS absolute positioned elements and margins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24373683/css-absolute-positioned-elements-and-margins)

The example below is a simplified version of a multilevel dropdown menu, in which list items are generated dynamically. Meaning that is not possible to know the actual width beforehand (unless some javascript is implemented). The ">" with yellow background indicates another dropdown level. I'd like to have **5px margin** between the end of the text and the ">".

See http://jsfiddle.net/3jzx8jh3

```
ul.level1 {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100px;
}

ul.level2 {
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

span.right {
    margin-left: 5px;
    float: right;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: yellow;
}

li {
    white-space: nowrap;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}


<ul class="level1">
    <li>Link1</li>
    <li>Link2
        <ul class="level2">
            <li><span class="right">></span>Fear is the path to the dark side</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I've noticed that when I set margin-left to about 190px, the ">" starts moving right. Meaning that the margin is indeed set in respect of the non statically positioned parent, this is the parent li element.

Can I get the margin as I wish just using css?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

instead of 
  `<li><span class="right">></span>Fear is the path to the dark side</li>`
use 
`<li>Fear is the path to the dark side <span class="right">></span></li>`

and remove `float : right` from your `.right`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, by doing that, if several list items have a submenu and therefore show the ">". These ">"s  are not going to be vertically aligned. I need the float to ensure that all of them are equally justified to the right, should there be more than one.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to post a possible solution using the flex box. This will be fine in firefox, chrome and IE11. However, it won't work in older IE versions, in which the ">"s won't be aligned one below the other.

The li element becomes a flex-box (display: flex), justified with equal space between elements (justify-content: space-between). The spans are not anymore floated.

```
ul.level1 {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100px;
}

ul.level2 {
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

span.right {
    margin-left: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: yellow;
}

li {
    white-space: nowrap;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

<ul class="level1">
    <li>Link1</li>
    <li>Link2
        <ul class="level2">
            <li>Fear is the path to the dark side<span class="right">></span></li>
            <li>Fear leads to anger<span class="right">></span></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The fiddle has been updated.