# Influence of margin-top of adjacent elements on a positioned element

Tags: html, css

I have 2 elements, each given a margin-top of 20px. The first one is positioned absolutely. Naturally, the second element ends up at the top and recedes from the edge of the screen by 20px.

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.posa {
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #1239;
}

.normal {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  background-color: #aaa9;
}
```

```html
<div class="posa">position</div>
<div class="normal">normal</div>
```

[CSS absolute positioned elements and margins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24373683/css-absolute-positioned-elements-and-margins) - This question was almost answered here, but it was talking about the parent element

Questions:

1. Why does an absolutely positioned element take the margin of the second element that was below?
2. Why don't their margins collapse so that the `.normal` element will recede from the top edge by 20px and the positioned element will recede by 40px.
3. Why does only the margin-top affect and the margin-left doesn't work that way?

Answer (score 1):

The `margin-top` of the normal element is collapsing with the body margin since it's the first in-flow child then the absolute element is using the body element as reference to move down. It's using its [static position](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54776182/8620333) since you didn't specify any top/left/right/bottom value

Add outline to the body element to notice this:

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.posa {
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #1239;
}

.normal {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  background-color: #aaa9;
}

body {
 outline: 1px solid red;
}
html {
 outline: 1px solid blue;
 outline-offset: -1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="posa">position</div>
<div class="normal">normal</div>
```

There is not margin collapsing on the left so the margin of the normal element will not affect the position of the absolute element.