# Vertically align a div with fixed positioning

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am new to stackoverflow and have searched through some of the other answers and tried a lot of different things but can't seem to get it right.

I need to vertically align the 'Hide Message' button with the paragraph of text so that the button appears in the centered alongside the text (jsFiddle link below). The button also needs to align with another div on the page so it has to have:

```
position: fixed;
right: 50px;
```

The main problem I am having with some of the other solutions is that if you shrink the browser, it doesn't stay vertically aligned with the text:

http://jsfiddle.net/d3R6v/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `position: fixed;` is a way to go here, instead of using `fixed` you should be using `absolute` but before that assign `position: relative;` to the parent element and modify your `#hideMessage` as

```
#hideMessage {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    right: 50px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -15px; /* Negate 1/2 the total height of the button, 
                          this value currently is approx */
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/d3R6v/3/)

The reason I insisted `position: absolute;` is because that it will align related to the parent element whereas using `fixed` is relative to the viewport.

For more information over positioning, you can [refer my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20718577/)

---

#### If you have dynamic text

Coming to more cleaner solution, it would be better if you use `display: table;` for the parent element, and `display: table-cell;` for the child elements, and for the parent element of the button i.e now `display: table-cell;`, you can use `vertical-align: middle;` to vertically align the button to the dynamic text on the left hand side and also on resize, the button won't overlap the text.

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/d3R6v/4/)

```
#parent {
    background-color: #bbb;
    color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    display: table;
}
#text {
    width: 80%;
    display: table-cell;
}
#hideMessage {
    display: table-cell;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}

#hello {
    background-color: #555;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    white-space: nowrap; /* Add if you want to prevent the 
                            button to wrap on resize */
}
```