# Bar height ignoring the height of the text itself

Tags: html, css

This is my code so far. The issue is that the top bar is too thin, it's meant to have 20px padding around the top links but in total the top bar is only 40px high, so it seems it isn't taking into account the height of the links themselves (i.e the bar should be taller). How do I fix this?

```css
    body {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      background-color: white;
      font-family: sans-serif;
    }
    
    header {
      display: block;
      padding: 20px;
      background-color: #F9F9F9;
    }
    
    #headerbar {
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .container {
      width: 80%;
      max-width: 1000px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    .logo {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
    }
    
    .post {
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
    }
```

```html
   <header>
      <div id="headerbar" class="container">
        <a href="#" class="logo">Logo</a>
        <a href="#" class="post">Post</a>
      </div>
    </header>
```

Comment: Because logo is `position: absolute` it's essentially floating on top of the header, not in it - therefore padding is working as it should

Comment: @DarrenSweeney Is there a way to make the padding or a margin apply? Is the only option to use floats or specify a height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes to `.logo` and `.post` classes

```css
    body {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      background-color: white;
      font-family: sans-serif;
    }
    
    header {
      display: block;
      padding: 20px;
      background-color: #F9F9F9;
    }
    
    #headerbar {
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .container {
      width: 80%;
      max-width: 1000px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    .logo {
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .post {
      position: relative;
      float: right;
    }
```

```html
   <header>
      <div id="headerbar" class="container">
        <a href="#" class="logo">Logo</a>
        <a href="#" class="post">Post</a>
      </div>
    </header>
```

Comment: What did you change?

Comment: Have a look at `.logo` and `.post` classes -- will highlight in answer

Answer (score 1):

As @Darren said in the comment, the issue lies in `absolute` positioning ([See this answer for more details how it works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20718728/1763929)). One way to fix this is to use `float`, and clear after it.

[Clearfix styles from HTML5Boilerplate](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/dist/css/main.css):

```
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

```css
    body {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      background-color: white;
      font-family: sans-serif;
    }
    
    header {
      display: block;
      padding: 20px;
      background-color: #F9F9F9;
    }
    
    #headerbar {
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .container {
      width: 80%;
      max-width: 1000px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    .logo {
      float:left;
    }
    
    .post {
      float:right;
    }
    
    .clearfix:before,
    .clearfix:after {
        content: " "; /* 1 */
        display: table; /* 2 */
    }

    .clearfix:after {
        clear: both;
    }
```

```html
   <header>
      <div id="headerbar" class="container clearfix">
        <a href="#" class="logo">Logo</a>
        <a href="#" class="post">Post</a>
      </div>
    </header>
```

---

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1qymcLo3/)

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      background-color: white;
      font-family: sans-serif;
    }
    
    header {
      display: block;
     
      background-color: #F9F9F9;
    }
    
    #headerbar {
      
    padding: 20px;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .container {
      width: 80%;
      max-width: 1000px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    .logo {
      padding-bottom:50px;
      
     
    }
    
    .post {
      float:right;
    }
```

```html
<header>
      <div id="headerbar" class="container">
        <a href="#" class="logo">Logo</a>
        <a href="#" class="post">Post</a>
      </div>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

On a side note, I do not see any box sizing, font sizes and line heights added. These should all be working together to help correct spacing issues throughout devices.