# Can't understand relative property of position

Tags: html, css, layout, css-position

I'm learning CSS from basis and have done a small sample: https://jsfiddle.net/L290pjwb/

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.a {
  position: static;
}
.b {
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">A</div>
<div class="b">B</div>
<div class="b">B1</div>
```

Boxes are located in such way:

[image]

All right, I understood, that `position: static` is the default position model for HTML elements and it can't be relocated just by adding the `top, bottom, right, left` properties. `position: relative` is like `static`, but offers some kind of `offset`, which `static` can't.

My question is: **why isn't `B1` box located like this**:

[image]

?

Comment: Why do you think it should be like that?

Comment: Because it take the parent element for the positioning.

Comment: @NenadVracar The main point why am I confusing because of the last element. It has the left offset, but it doesn't have the top offset, despite on CSS-property "top: 10px; ". B1 box is located closely by top, but has offset from left where the simple B box has both top & left offset.

Comment: If you still need a visual reference. The red border, indicates where the box was *normally* before the offset. http://i.stack.imgur.com/FKiPZ.png .. So there **is** a top offset.

Comment: @AnkithAmtange Thanks, very useful! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relative positioning places the element where it would be if it was statically positioned and then offsets it from that position without influencing anything else.

B is put where it would be normally and then offset. B1 is put where it would be normally (i.e. immediately after where B **would be normally without positioning**) and then offset.

You would only get this effect [image] if the static position for B1 was calculated from the offset position of B instead of the static position of B.

If you want to move elements about and have their new position influence the position of other elements: **Use margins instead of relative positioning**.

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.a {
  position: static;
}
.b {
  position: static;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.b + .b {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">A</div>
<div class="b">B</div>
<div class="b">B1</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The [html](/questions/tagged/html) element is positioned like a `static` element, by only one difference. You can modify his position. But physically, the element is placed at `top: 0;` and `left: 0;`.

Here is a explication about the behavior.

> Using `position: relative;` is just like using `static` position, the difference >is making an element `position: relative;`, you will be able to use `top`, >`right`, `bottom` and `left` properties, though the element will move, but >physically it will be in the document flow..

[image]

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20718728/4575054).

Answer (score -1):

B1 isnt located as you ask because the top/left offset is aplied to their default position, what confuse you is that B and B1 doenst have offset from each other, thats because the new position does not affect other elements, try change 
.b top and left properties to margin-top and margin-left

Comment: `static` is the default. And you are confusing `static` with `fixed`.

Answer (score -1):

You are positioning the elements relative to where they would be placed in the normal flow. In this case, the div would occur after div B but would get the same style values and, therefore, be positioned the same as the other div.

Comment: "relative to their parent" — No. Relative positioning is relative to the position they would have if they were position: static.

Comment: @Quentin Whoops! You are correct. I'm so used to the question asking about absolutely positioned elements within relative boxes. Fixed.

Answer (score -1):

Hey you can add id to B1 and just put margin:10px; It will give result what you want.

```css
div {
    width      : 50px;
    height     : 50px;
    border     : 1px solid black;
    box-sizing : border-box;
}

.a {
    position: static;
}

.b {
    position : relative;
    top      : 10px;
    left     : 10px;
    width    : 100px;
    height   : 100px;
}
#B1 {
margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class = "a">A</div>
<div class = "b">B</div>
<div class = "b" id="B1">B1</div>
```

Comment: The point of this question is to understand `position` property (layout system) for DOM elements mixing different available values, *NOT* just achieving the final picture result with any available CSS property.