# Logo Over Multiple Divs at once

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a website and have designed the header [image]

The Red and Blue is an image
The Yellow is a navigation bar
The circle is a logo
My issue is that I am unable to put the logo in div of the image and the nav div at the same time. Is this even possible or should I consider a new design. Perhaps I am looking at this incorrectly.

Comment: This can simply be achieved with `margin-top: -50px;`. However, you would need to provide some code in order to state **exactly** what your code should look like.

Comment: You are downvoted because you don't show your code and what exactly doesn't work for you. I didn't downvote, this is just a friendly piece of explanation for you.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How CSS Positions work, why absolute elements stack up on each other instead of stacking one after other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20718577/how-css-positions-work-why-absolute-elements-stack-up-on-each-other-instead-of)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is about having the same image on both the nav and that div.

[Pen here!](https://jsfiddle.net/o8gfr00m/)

You can do it easily with background-image and set the same image aswell.

```
  background-image: url(http://s.glbimg.com/jo/g1/f/original/2016/05/02/palestinian-gaza-daily_life_mohammed_abed_afp.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  backgroud-position: center center;
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using pure CSS. This is a possible approach to get what you want:

```css
#one {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#two {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 100px;
  transform: translateY(40px);
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 1;
}

#three {
  position: relative;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: yellow;
  bottom: -20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="one">
  <div id="two">
  </div>
  <div id="three">
  </div>
</div>
```

Replace *divs* with any block element and it should work too. Otherwise, you'll need to set `display: block`.