# How can I position an element on top of another while retaining document flow?

Tags: html, css

I have an example where I'm stacking a black div on top of a red div using position absolute. Then more content follows.

```css
p {
  position: relative;
  z-index; 10
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

#red {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
}

#black {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <p>Hello</p>
  <div id="red"></div>
  <div id="black"></div>
  <p>World</p>
</div>
```

How can I make it so `World` appears below the red div in flow with the rest of the DOM while retaining the stacked divs as they are.

**Desired outcome:**
[image]
The solution must use the regular DOM flow to achieve this. I.e. setting `World` to `position: absolute` and manually placing it in the right place is not what I want. Also preferably no JS used.

The crux of this issue is that I don't know how to stack elements without using `position: absolute` which takes the elements outside the DOM flow. But perhaps there is a better way to stack elements.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using position:absolute while keeping it inside the document flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18598031/using-positionabsolute-while-keeping-it-inside-the-document-flow)

Comment: It is but I think the answer below is cleaner than those answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the feeling this is too simple and may not be what you are looking for. But I got rid of all of the positioning and put the black square inside the red.

```css
#red {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}

#black {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <p>Hello</p>
  
  <div id="red">
    <div id="black"></div>
  </div>
  
  <p>World</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Oof. This made me feel dumb. This is what I want. Thank you