# How to get elements to line up using flexbox when blog titles vary in length

Tags: css, html, flexbox, alignment

I'm trying to create a blog page which displays the thumbnail, title, date and categories of each blog. Due to varying blog titles the elements don't line up properly. Ideally I would like the date, categories and read more button to line up horizontally with the neighbouring blog listing. However I would also settle for just the read more buttons being aligned at the bottom if this isn't possible. I've attached an image to show the misalignment.

```
<div class="flex-container">
  <article>
    <img />
    <h2>title</h2>
    <p>date</p>
    <p>category 1, category 2</p>
    <a>read more</a>
  </article>
</div>

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap; }

article {
  width: 50%;

}
```

[image showing elements not lining up properly due to one long blog title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtfRQ.png)

Comment: Can you share any jsfiddle or codepen link to see how you implemented?

Comment: You are applying flex to individual articles, you need to apply flex to the container the articles are in so that you can make all the articles the same height, after that you can then make adjustments within the articles so that at least the button lines up at the bottom.

Comment: sorry @JoseGuerra that's what I do have - I've updated the code to reflect it

Comment: **You can't**. There is no CSS mechanism to align elements **that do not share a parent**. You only option would be to align everything *after* the title to the bottom. In which case - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20830878/aligning-an-element-to-the-bottom-of-a-container?rq=1

Comment: @Suresh a basic codepen can be seen here https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YMdoQj

Comment: In shared codepen link flex property is applying on article. It should wrapped up with any div and then apply it so that child containers will flex benifits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the `article` elements flex as well, and then simply use the “magic” of `margin:auto` in combination with flexbox, by applying `margin-bottom: auto` for the `h2`:

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap; }

article {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 50%;
}

article h2 {
  margin-bottom: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <article>
    <img />
    <h2>title</h2>
    <p>date</p>
    <p>category 1, category 2</p>
    <a>read more</a>
  </article>
  <article>
    <img />
    <h2>really<br>long<br>title</h2>
    <p>date</p>
    <p>category 1, category 2</p>
    <a>read more</a>
  </article>
</div>
```